How can I restore a Macrium Image if the image exists but does not show in the Macrium App?
I have a Windows 10 Pro machine and I have created a Macrium RE system drive image on an external drive and want to do a restore. But the MRIMG file does not show in the main application window "Existing Backups".
How can I do a restore?

Have you checked the documentation for the software? There should be a way to search or locate existing backups.

I know which drives the backups are in, but do I just double click on them or what?

In the dialog below, there are two ways shown to select an image file.

At the bottom is the list of files made on that computer. It might not be complete, or accurate -- for example an external drive might have had an image stored on it when it had the drive letter F:, but if the drive is currently E:, the location would be wrong.
At the top is a button to use the standard file open dialog. Click that button to browse to the image file, even one created on another machine.


Double-click a folder with the image in the file open dialog, or click it and select Open. Then follow the directions, as they are shown, to either mount ("Browse") the image and access specific files, or restore that image, overwriting one or more partitions on the drive.
BTW, I find restoring a drive surprisingly fast!

@PxB - I suggest you simply try to load the backup. task.
